# getElementById() is null?

Tags: javascript, html, image, src, createelement

So I am trying to make a JavaScript program that will take a URL for an image and then put it onto the page while creating an `<img>` tag so that I can just continue pasting as many photos as I want. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Low-Budget Online Album</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
    function init() {
        var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
        button.onclick = buttonClick;
    }
window.onload = init;

    function buttonClick() {
        var imageSource = document.getElementById("imageInput").value;
        if (imageSource == "") {
            alert("Please enter the source for an image.");
        }
        else {
            var newImage = document.createElement("img");
            var newSrc = document.getElementById("newImage").src= imageSource;
    
            imageInput.value = "";
        }
    }       
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="imageInput" size="40" placeholder="Image Source">
<input type="button" id="addButton" value="Add Image">
<img id="images" src="">
</img>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, is that when I put int a URL (or picture src from my PC) it says that `TypeError: document.getElementById(...)` is null, and points to line 20, being my

`var newSrc = document.getElementById("newImage").src= imageSource;`

line. Any ideas?

Comment: when you call `document.createElement("img")` you don't add id attribute to image, also you don't add it to document

Comment: How do I give it an ID while simultaneously creating it? And why is it not being added to the document? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean something like this:

```
function init() {    
    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = buttonClick;    
}
window.onload = init;

function buttonClick() {        
    var imageSource = document.getElementById("imageInput").value;
    if (imageSource == "") {
        alert("Please enter the source for an image.");
    }
    else {
        var newImage = document.createElement("img");
        newImage.src= imageSource;
        newImage.setAttribute("id", "newImage");
        imageInput.value = "";
        document.body.appendChild(newImage);
    }
}
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ryyu/)

Comment: Thanks, this helped it work :) Now it adds the image, but it can only do it from the folder this file is located in. Any ideas how to make it so I can add and path or even a URL into it and have it work?

Comment: @nanowaffle if you mean you want to upload a file then you need to have input element of type 'file', like <input type='file' name='some_name' value='' />

Comment: You are creating an element with a fixed `id`, which means that if you create multiple elements they all get the same `id`. That means you're creating invalid html. If the `id` is used for styling, a class name would suffice too.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
else {
        var newImage = document.createElement("img"); //this line creates element <img> element in the dom.
        newImage.setAttribute("id", "newImage");             
        newImage.src= imageSource;
        document.body.appendChild(newImage);//adds element <img src="a.jpg" id='newImage'>to the dom.
        imageInput.value = "";
    }
```

Understand what mistake you have done above:

1.First you created element and assign to a variable newImage

```
 var newImage=document.createElement("img");
```

2.You are calling

```
 document.getElementById('newImage');
```

Here newImage as element that you created and in the dom there is no element with id as `newImage` so you were getting null.

Comment: `document.createElement()` creates a new element but does not add it to the DOM. You need to do that yourself, because only you know where it should go.

Comment: Main mistake he was doing that he was creating the element newImage and considering that element as id so he was getting as null. I added the element to dom reading your comment.Thanks

Comment: That's true. Your changes now create an element with a fixed `id`, which means that if you create several elements, they all will get the same `id`. I wouldn't use the id attribute at all. If needed for styling, a class name will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement) you can see that `createElement` only create element and not add it to DOM. So if you want add created element you need change your code like this

```
var newImage = document.createElement("img");
newImage.id = "newImage";
document.body.appendChild(newImage);
```

after this line will work

```
var newSrc = document.getElementById("newImage").src= imageSource;
```

but you don't need get find it if you already have this image in `newImage` variable, so this line you can change like

```
var newSrc = newImage.src= imageSource;
```

**UPDATE**
Possibly you need use `className` instead of `id` because `id` should be unique on page, but as i understand you want add many images

Answer (score 0):

```
var newImage = document.createElement("img");
var newSrc = document.getElementById("newImage").src= imageSource;
```

Become:

```
var newImage = document.createElement("img");
newImage.setAttribute('id','newImage');
var newSrc = document.getElementById("newImage").src = imageSource;
```